# How to remove spaces in the bottom of the UITextView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

i am using `UITextView` and i want to remove spaces in the bottom of the `UITextview`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated above code.try with it.i think you got desire result..

```
// Create a size with large height, but matching width to UITextView.
[myTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(myTextView.frame.size.width, 20);

// Determine the size needed to display the text - we just need the new height.
CGSize textSize = [myTextView.text sizeWithFont:myTextView.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// Set the UITextView's frame to the new height.
CGRect textViewRect = myTextView.frame;
textViewRect.size.height = textSize.height+13;
myTextView.frame = textViewRect;
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

`textView.text = [textView.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];`

Comment: This answer was written before attributed text had been introduced in iOS...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming/guessing you wish to resize a UITextView to accommodate the text nicely.  If so, I suggest you investigate:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

For example:

```
// Create a size with large height, but matching width to UITextView.
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(myTextView.frame.size.width, 9999);

// Determine the size needed to display the text - we just need the new height.
CGSize textSize = [myTextView.text sizeWithFont:myTextView.font constrainedToSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

// Set the UITextView's frame to the new height.
CGRect textViewRect = myTextView.frame;
textViewRect.size.height = textSize.height;
myTextView.frame = textViewRect;
```

Comment: i have to write - (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font constrainedToSize:(CGSize)size lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
 method in .h file ?

Comment: textViewRect.height = textSize.height;
 line shows error

Comment: No, it's an NSString instance method, so you can just include it in your code without declaring it in the interface.

Comment: Sorry about error - now edited.

Comment: it is not working . i can not enter text in textview

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I think you need to add more details to your question to help us understand how/what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hi, i think you need to set background color of UITextVIew so you can see actual content size of it. Thanks